# Best Portable Recorder For Art Installations 

Tags: field-recording, sound-effects

Guys, I'm a poet who is going to do an experimental poetry project. I want to record sounds of the landscape for my show. I guess it's something like doing filed recording. What portable recorder do you recommend for someone new in the field but who wants the best audio? I don't want to spend more than $150.

Answer (score 3):

Zoom H2 is a safe bet.

Answer (score 3):

I can personally recommend the Zoom products. I personally have the H4n Series which is a bit more pricey - http://www.zoom.co.jp/english/products/h4n/ However they have a great reputation for portable recorders and the mics are very high quality.  If the other guys are saying the H2 is a good shout, id go for it!

Hope this helps!

Gillian

Comment: I went to the Chicago Museum of Modern Art and recorded a lot of different crowd & room sounds with the H2. I highly recommend that if you're not getting the H4.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider renting some gear if this is a 1 time deal.  Many cities have audio rental houses.  You can probably get a Zoom H2 for $20-30/day or less.

DO you have more specific info on what you want to capture?  The more we know about what you are recording, the more the SSD community can help.  Is it possible that a sound library of ambiances might work?